# TortoiseSVN plugin help "Failed to start issue tracker COM provider %plugin%"

Tags: plugins, tortoisesvn

I have a fully working plugin for tortoiseSVN(x86).  It does everything I would like but I cannot get it to work on x64 machines.  It properly installs, registers, appears when you click the button...but when you hit commit this is what I get this output:

> Action                    Path
>   Command             Commit
>   Modified                C:\Test2\README.txt
>   Sending content    C:\Test2\README.txt
>   Completed                       At revision: 17
>   Error                                    Failed to start the issue tracker COM provider 'SCRFixerPlugIn'.
>   Error                                    Invalid pointer
>   Error                                    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can find no specific references to these errors.  Again it works very well on 32 bit...but I just can't get it to work with no errors on 64bit.

Thank you for any help!

David

Comment: I figured this out...This is due to an improper return in OnCommitFinished.  There was a function left over from a previous programmer that called an obselete function that works of 32bit dll.  Whoops!  Hope this helps if anyone else has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...This is due to an improper return in OnCommitFinished. There was a function left over from a previous programmer that called an obselete function that works on 32bit dll. Whoops! Hope this helps if anyone else has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update has helped. You can find it here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999